# What did Mako say?

Tags: pacific-rim

Right before the detonation of the large nuke, Mako said something to Stacker. It wasn't subtitled and I don't speak Japanese. What did she say?

Comment: there are also two words commonly used for love in japanese ai is more like something you would say to a parent (dad I love you) koi is what you would say to your girlfriend/boyfriends (hey babe I love you)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

She said 「せんせい あいしてます」(sensei aishitemasu), which means "I love you teacher/elder."  This was [confirmed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/travisbeacham/statuses/356618165930831875) by Travis Beacham, *Pacific Rim's* screenwriter.

Mako Mori is a Japanese name, which was my first clue that she's Japanese. The others were that the language she and the Marshall spoke early on was Japanese, and the city in her flashback was adorned with signs that had Japanese, not Chinese, on them.

Comment: For some strange reason, I always hear it as English in my mind. I was watching it with subtitles, so I suppose that's why.

Comment: I don't think she actually said "sensei" in the movie. I just listened back, and it sounds way more like "oto-san". Even if Travis' are word of god, I have a feeling he made a mistake there.

Answer (score 11):

She said "aishitemasu" which is "I love you" in Japanese.